# Estimating the sample variance and expected value of a maximization function of multiple random variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, function, multivariate-distribution

Suppose I have three i.i.d. random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. A model is used to generate $i$ outcomes for each variable that are used to estimate the sample mean and sample variance for each of the random variables. Where $x_i$, $y_i$, and $z_i$ correspond to the $i$th outcome of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, respectively, and $x_i \geq 0 $, $y_i \geq 0 $, $z_i \geq 0 $ for all $i$. We can assume $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ take on a normal distribution, but we cannot assume equal variances.

If we let $g(X, Y, Z)$ = $\max(X, Y, Z)$, is there a way to estimate $E[g(X, Y, Z)]$ and $Var[g(X, Y, Z)]$ from simulated outputs? Is there a theorem I should look into?

**Example Simulated Model Outcomes for $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ **

| $i$ | $x_i$ | $y_i$ | $z_i$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.1 | 11.5 | 14.1 |
| 2 | 4.8 | 10.1 | 16.3 |
| 3 | 5.2 | 10.0 | 11.8 |
| 4 | 4.9 | 9.5 | 15.3 |
| 5 | 5.0 | 9.7 | 13.7 |

Comment: Since you have *iid* realizations of the *single* random variable $g(X,Y,Z),$ your question answers itself: you estimate the mean and variance in exactly the same way you would estimate the mean and variance for any variable *without making distributional assumptions.*  The usual estimates are the sample mean and (bias-corrected) sample variance.